# simple question for 2 order DE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

I want to get some plots from this equation under any boundary condition(y[0]=0,y'[0]= 0)!! but I guess there is some singular point.

```
 Clear["Global`*"]
 a=.003;b=0.3;f=10^-6;
 sol = DSolve[{(y''[x]/ y[x]) + (y'[x]/ y[x])^2 - a (y'[x]/y[x]) + b (1/y[x]^2) - f==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0},y,{x,0,10}]
 Plot[{y'[x]/y[x] /. sol, y[x] /. sol}, {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is having hard time solving for the constants $c_1,c_2$ from the general solution. Here is a possible workaround.

Solve for the general solution with no initial conditions imposed. Then setup 2 equations using the two initial conditions and manually solve for $c_1,c_2$.

The general solution contains 2 solutions. This below uses the first solution. You can do the same for the second solution. Also, always use exact numbers with exact solvers to be safe.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 3/1000; b = 3/10; f = 10^-6;
ode = (y''[x]/y[x]) + (y'[x]/y[x])^2 - a (y'[x]/y[x]) + b (1/y[x]^2) -f == 0;
bc = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

setup two equations

```
 (* for y[0]==0 *)
 eq1 = 0 == sol /. x -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solve for $c_1$ from the above in terms of $c_2$

```
solC1 = First@Solve[eq1, C[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* for y'[0]==0 *)
eq2 = 0 == D[sol, x] /. x -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Substitute $c_1$ from the above into eq2

```
eq2 = eq2 /. solC1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solve for $c_2$

```
eq3 = Numerator[eq2[[2]]] == 0;
solC2 = First@Solve[eq3, C[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Substitute $c_1,c_2$ in the general solution above

```
solFinal = sol /. solC1;
solFinal = solFinal /. solC2
```

The above too large to post. A simplified version is

```
FullSimplify[solFinal]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Verification

```
solFinalVerify = y -> Function[{x}, Evaluate[solFinal]];
ode /. solFinalVerify // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Verify solution against BC:

```
bc /. solFinalVerify // Simplify
(* {True,True} *)
```

Notice that the above solution becomes complex for some $x$ values.

```
Table[solFinal /. x -> i, {i, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Maple's solution to compare with

```
restart;
a := 3/1000; b := 3/10; f := 10^(-6):
ode := (diff(y(x),x$2)/y(x)) + (diff(y(x),x)/y(x))^2 - a *(diff(y(x),x)/y(x)) + b*(1/y(x)^2) -f = 0:
bc := y(0) = 0,D(y)(0)=0:
sol :=dsolve([ode,bc],y(x))
```

When adding BC, Maple can't solve it. It gives

```
 sol := NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Nasser, there's no any plot!!

Comment: @ArminSharafi as I mentioned the solution to your ode is complex. You can't use `Plot` on it, it will come out empty. You have to plot either the real, complex or abs values. Something like `Plot[Abs@solFinal, {x, 0, 1}]`  btw, it will also help to mention in your question where did the ODE come from. Is it physics based or did you just make it or it is from a book?

Comment: Yes dude, come from physics